# Jquery tree traversing not working

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery variable that isnt working and it's most likeley because i don't know how to select elements properly.  I thought the below selectors would work, but they don't

JQUERY:

```
$('.upVote').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ratebox = $(this).find('.ratingBox');  //this variable isnt working
    var answer_id = $(this).children('.record_id').attr('value');  //this one too
```

HTML:

```
<p class='ratingBox'> $answerrating[$f]</p>
<div class='answerBar'>";
    <a href='#' class='upVote vote'>Upvote</a> 
    &middot;
    <a href='#' class='downVote vote'>Downvote</a>  
    <a class='answerTime'> $difference $periods[$j] ago</a>
</div> 
<input type='hidden' name='record_id' value='$answerid[$f]' class='record_id' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `find()` and `children()` will look for elements lower in the DOM tree than the current - the elements you're looking for are both higher. Try this:

```
var ratebox = $(this).closest('.answerBar').prev(".ratingBox");
var answer_id = $(this).closest('.answerBar').next('.record_id').attr('value');
```

[**Fiddle to prove it works**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Su5Hm/)

Answer (score 0):

Use should make use of `parent`, `prev` and `next`. Because `find` and `children` will look in the element which will not work as per your markup. Try this

```
$('.upVote').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var ratebox = $(this).parent().prev('.ratingBox');  //this will work now
  var answer_id = $(this).parent().next('.record_id').attr('value');  //this too

});
```

Comment: thanks but it didnt work. i dont see why would next work.  donest next get the very next element? or the very next element within the selector?